# Why does my code not display a google ad and fail to communicate with another viewController?

Tags: swift, admob

I'm making a game where in, if you lose, you get a UIView popup asking if you'd like to view a video add to gain another life. My popUp code is as follows:

```
class Popup: UIView, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {


func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
     GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    let ViewController().lifeNumber += 1

 }

let playButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func play() {
    print("Play button pressed")
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {

//I THINK THE ISSUE IS THE NEXT LINE OF CODE
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController:ViewController())               
//            
    }
    }

fileprivate let popUpContainer: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 22
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

@objc fileprivate func popupDisappear() {
    self.alpha = 0
}

@objc fileprivate func popupAppear() {
    self.alpha = 1
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(popupDisappear)))
    self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.addSubview(popUpContainer)
    popUpContainer.addSubview(playButton)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    popUpContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
    popUpContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
    popUpContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.55),
    popUpContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),

    playButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpContainer.centerXAnchor),
    playButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpContainer.centerYAnchor),
    playButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    playButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
            ])
    popupAppear()
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Could not run init(coder)")
    }
}
```

And here is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var lifeNumber: 3

    lazy var lifeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(lifeNumber)"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 25)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubView(lifeLabel)

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
        let pop = Popup()
        self.view.addSubview(pop)

    }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do here is, when the popUp appears, it displays a button to view a video advert. Pressing that button displays the ad, and once its done and you dismiss the popUp, the label that displays the number of lives increases by 1.

However, with my code, the ad does not come up, even though the print command does execute; and the label in my ViewController fails to change. I've tried using protocols but that didn't really help much with the result.

Be really grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: The obvious question? If your `print` code line is hit, how about the line *inside* the `if` statement that follows? (`GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()...`) In other words, is `GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true`?

Comment: @dfd the same code works if I simply make the ViewController a delegate of Admob, I really doubt that is the issue here.  I think the issue is me trying to make PopUp class an object of the GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate, but I can't get my head around what exactly